# Extracting useful info from pandas column containing dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Category    Data     Age
A1            30     {'Age1_Set': 25.6, 'WIndex': 343.3, 'Age2_Set': 22.6}
A2            20     {'Age1_Set': 35.2, 'WIndex': 343.3, 'Age2_Set': 42.1}
A3            20     {'Age1_Set': 26.5, 'WIndex': 343.3, 'Age2_Set': 11.1}
```

My pandas df is like above. Age should be the min of 'Age1_Set' and 'Age2_Set'. I am able to deal with this if Age was not a dict and rather three columns.

My output is:

```
Category    Data     Age
A1            30     22.6
A2            20     35.2
A3            20     11.1
```

How can this be done?

EDIT:
I have another entry in original df

```
Category    Data     Age
A4            20
```

Age is null basically. How to deal with such case.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Did you try iterating over your Age Series ? Once you do that you should easily be able to access each dictionary's values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Category": ["A1", "A2", "A3"],
                   "Data": [30, 20, 20],
                   "Age": [{'Age1_Set': 25.6, 'WIndex': 343.3, 'Age2_Set': 22.6}, {'Age1_Set': 35.2, 'WIndex': 343.3, 'Age2_Set': 42.1}, {'Age1_Set': 26.5, 'WIndex': 343.3, 'Age2_Set': 11.1}]})

df["Min_Age"] = [min(x["Age1_Set"], x["Age2_Set"]) for x in df.Age]

print(df)
```

Result:

```
  Category  Data                                                Age  Min_Age
0       A1    30  {'Age1_Set': 25.6, 'WIndex': 343.3, 'Age2_Set'...     22.6
1       A2    20  {'Age1_Set': 35.2, 'WIndex': 343.3, 'Age2_Set'...     35.2
2       A3    20  {'Age1_Set': 26.5, 'WIndex': 343.3, 'Age2_Set'...     11.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new dataframe from the dictionaries in the `Age` column, then `filter` the `Age` like columns and use `min` along `axis=1` to get the minimum of age from `Age1_Set` and `Age2_Set`:

```
df['Age'] = pd.DataFrame(df['Age'].tolist()).filter(like='Age').min(1)
```

Alternatively you can also use `Series.str.get` + `np.minimum`:

```
df['Age'] = np.minimum(df['Age'].str.get('Age1_Set'), df['Age'].str.get('Age2_Set'))
```

---

```
  Category  Data   Age
0       A1    30  22.6
1       A2    20  35.2
2       A3    20  11.1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to compare these two values of the dict, you can use the following method:

```
df['Age']=df['Age'].apply(lambda x: min(x["Age1_Set"], x["Age2_Set"]))
```

This avoids the hassle of converting the dictionary to other data formats and is IMO easily readable.

If you need to more complex logic, then you might want to extract the lambda into its own function. For example, when you need to deal with entries that are None:

```py
def get_min_age(entry:dict)->float:
    if entry is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return min(entry["age1"], entry["age2"])
df['Age']=df['Age'].apply(get_min_age)
```

### A note on performance:

Using `.apply()` is not an ideal approach when dealing with large datasets (>100k rows), since it treats every row in a sequential way.

If you notice that performance becomes a bottleneck, the vectorized methods in the other answers will be more performant ([as this article explains in more detail](https://medium.com/bigdatarepublic/advanced-pandas-optimize-speed-and-memory-a654b53be6c2)).

Comment: I've added an example. If you can add extra logic there if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass your data column without any extra params.

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['Age'])
```